# Difference between "at that time" / "that time"

Tags: meaning, differences

What's the difference between **at that time / that time**?

> When I faced the issue previously, at that time John helped us to resolve it.
>   When I faced the issue previously, that time John helped us to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

**at that time**:  during  a specific time in the past ( last week, last month etc)

**that time**: on  that specific occasion.

Answer (score 0):

At that time means a prior time that is being brought up to refer to something that someone is saying in the moment about a previous time. That time refers to a particular instance.

Comment: William, how is this adding anything meaningful? It's really just a re-wording of an existing answer. Please read [answer], and take the **[Tour]** of the site to get a better understanding of what the EL&U community expects.